# Sharing Internet between two PCs

Tags: internet, sharing

I have a LAN connected internet connection on a WIN7 PC1. How do I share this internet connection with another WIN10 PC2? I also want PC2 not to be discovered on the network on which PC1 is.

(my best guess is using a usb to Ethernet between PC1 and PC2)

kindly detail the procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can make the PC1 as wifi hotspot device following the below steps and share the internet

http://www.pcninja.us/turn-your-windows-7-laptop-into-a-wifi-hotspot/

Answer (score 0):

If you have two nic you can bridge the connection by going to the **network connection** settings in the control center. Select *both* nic, right click on one and select **bridge connection**.

[image: Select both adapters and click on Bridge connection in context menu]

With your firewall you can control what network traffic can get to which network.